# Looping through elements with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a slideshow app using AngularJS that uses Instagram photos filtered by a specific tag. Here is the [demo](http://metrogram.konstruktors.com/) and the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/kasparsd/metrogram).

**What is the most efficient way of looping through those images according to the principles of AngularJS?**

Currently I use a `$timeout` which moves the first element to the bottom of the `images` array in combination with CSS which hides every other image except the first one:

```
$scope.images = [
    'image-001.jpg',
    'image-002.jpg',
    'image-003.jpg'
];

$timeout( function advanceSlide() {
    $scope.images.push( $scope.images.shift() );
    $timeout( advanceSlide, 6000 );
);
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/YruT6/1/

The other option would be to walk the `photos` object and apply an `active` class, like [illustrated here](https://github.com/kasparsd/metrogram/blob/d620e13bacd06c33b147e189879aaf2bb005c0b5/assets/metrogram.js#L36). Would that be less resource intensive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution works OK but using a repeater might not be the best strategy as:

- all the images will be in the DOM all the time
- using a repeater and manipulating an array will result in a the repeater re-calculation and DOM reshuffle.

So, for a bigger slideshow you would have many elements in the DOM and frequent / slow DOM manipulations. I could propose an alternative approach:

```
$scope.imgIndex = 0;
$timeout(function advanceSlide() {
    $scope.imgIndex = ($scope.imgIndex + 1) % $scope.images.length; 
    $timeout(advanceSlide, 1000);
});
```

and then in a template:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="slideshow">
    <img ng-src="{{images[imgIndex].src}}">
</div>​
```

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ThmeZ/6/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Pawel! That is a really good point. I ended up using ng-repeat and toggling only the `active` ng-class which seems to have drastically reduced memory usage and trigger re-paint only for the list elements with the `active` toggle.